# OpenCV Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++

Hello guys I am developing a simple openCV application with eclipse CDT;
Here is my code

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat M(2,2, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,255));
    cout << "M = " << endl << " " << M << endl << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I have built the project and when I try to run, I am getting this error
The program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist
D:\AndroidKeyStore\ExOpen\Debug\ExOpen.exe not found

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming the compilation didn't fail**, the executable you're building appears to be different from the one you're trying to run in your configuration.

I'm not familiar with Eclipse CDT but you should

- go to the *Debug Configurations* window for your project
- select your launch configuration
- change the exe you pasted above to the one your project is configured to build (you can find it in the project properties->C/C++ Build->Build directory)

[image]

Comment: After compiling exe file is not created

Comment: Then it must be something else. Check the error log for errors.